# How to create a heap of balls and keep it within the screen on ground in lua and corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How to create a heap of balls and keep it within the screen on the ground in lua and corona sdk?

Right now it is falling down from the screen and disappear from the screen.

```
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()

--local sky = display.newImage("sky.png")
--sky:scale( 5, 10 )
--sky.x = -100
--sky.y = -200

local field = display.newImage("field.png")
field:scale( 5, 10 )
field.x = 240
field.y = 470
local sky = display.newImage("sky.png")
sky:scale( 10, 3 )

physics.addBody(field,{friction = 0.5})
field.bodyType = "static"
local football = display.newImage("football.png")
football.x = 180
football.y = 80
football.rotation = 20
physics.addBody(football,{density = 2.0,friction = 0.5,bounce =0.5})

local function fallingball_field()
local football = display.newImage("football.png")
football.x = math.random(400)
football.y = -100
football.rotation = 20
physics.addBody(football, { density = 4.0,friction = 0.5, bounce = 0.5})
end
timer.performWithDelay(200, fallingball_field,200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to put your physics objects within the screen you must create a **"Boundary box"** that will keep your ball within the screen. Bellow is an example on how to create a boundary:

```
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()
physics.setDrawMode("hybrid")


local myCircle = display.newCircle( 100, 100, 30 )
myCircle:setFillColor( 0.5 )

local leftWall = display.newRect(0,display.contentCenterY, 10, display.contentHeight)
local rightWall = display.newRect(display.contentWidth,display.contentCenterY, 10, display.contentHeight)
local bottomWall = display.newRect(display.contentCenterX, display.contentHeight - 25, display.contentWidth, 10)
local topWall = display.newRect(display.contentCenterX, 25, display.contentWidth, 10)

leftWall:setFillColor(nil)
rightWall:setFillColor(nil)
bottomWall:setFillColor(nil)
topWall:setFillColor(nil)

physics.addBody (leftWall, "static", { bounce = 0.1} )
physics.addBody (rightWall, "static", { bounce = 0.1} )
physics.addBody (bottomWall, "static", { bounce = 0.1} )
physics.addBody (topWall, "static", { bounce = 0.1} )
physics.addBody (myCircle, "dynamic", { bounce = 1.5} )
```

Explanation: 
The **"walls"** will keep your physics objects into place assuming that your app is set to ***horizontal*** this will work as is. let me know if your application is ***vertical***.

The ***physics.setDrawMode("hybrid")*** will show the physics boundaries of **EACH** objects that you set with a physics body.It will be easier to see how your objects interact to each other.